# Empty Array in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 columns:
 - `name` (type: string)
 - `order_id` (type: int)

What I want to do is this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id) AS ids
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  name
```

The problem is, the `order_id` column has some empty fields. Not all names will correspond to an id. What I want is a table with 2 columns (name, ids) where all names from the original table are still there, and if there were no corresponding ids the ids field should just be NULL/empty. If there were corresponding ids, then the ids column should contain an array of all `order_ids` belonging to that name. When I try to use `ARRAY_AGG` on empty fields I get: `"Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field ids"`

The following works but is slow. Is there any way to get the same result more efficiently?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT name FROM table)
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id FROM table GROUP BY name)
```

I have also tried to use:

```
CASE
      WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id)) = 0 THEN NULL
      ELSE ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id)
    END AS ids
```

and

```
CASE
  WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id)) = 0 THEN []
  ELSE ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id)
END AS ids
```

It's not an option/solution to just put something in the empty fields, it needs to be an integer and any integer could be 'misinterpreted' as an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your problem description, I believe you want to use the `IGNORE NULLS` optional clause that is [documented under the `ARRAY_AGG()` StandardSQL function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg). As explained in the docs, what this clause does is to exclude `NULL` values from the result of the array creation.

Here you can see a simple example I prepared, based on your description:

Having a table like the one below:

[image]

We can perform a query with the `ARRAY_AGG()` function such as this one:

```
SELECT
  name,
  ARRAY_AGG(order_id IGNORE NULLS) as order_ids
FROM
  `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE`
GROUP BY
  name
ORDER BY
  name
```

In order to obtain the following results:

[image]

As you can see, the three conditions that you specified have been respected:

1. "*All names from the original table are still there*"
2. "*If there were no corresponding ids the ids field should just be NULL/empty*"
3. "*If there were corresponding ids, then the ids column should contain an
   array of all order_ids belonging to that name*"

Answer (score 2):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id IGNORE NULLS) ids
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY name
```

The "trick' here is in using of `IGNORE NULLS` - you can read more about [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg)

You can test, play with above using below dummy example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' name, 1 order_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', NULL
)
SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT order_id IGNORE NULLS) ids
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY name
```

with result

```
Row name    ids  
1   abc     1    
            2    
2   xyz
```